# Association using ES6 and default created Model (Model is not associated to Model)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, associations, model-associations

**What I am you doing?**

I am trying to add association to my Folder model, using default created Model by CLI.
Important note is that I am trying to associate model to himself, so **Folder.hasMany.Folder**.

**What do I trying to achieve?**

My expectation is that when I use this query:

```
const folders = Folder.findAll({where:{parent_id: null}, include: [{model: Folder, as: 'children'}]});
```

I should get folder structure with children under children property.

But instead of that I am constantly getting error "**Folder(model) is not associated to Folder(model)**"

Here is a code of my Folder model:

```
'use strict';
const { Sequelize, Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
class Folder extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
        Folder.hasMany(models.Folder, {
            foreignKey: 'parent_id',
            as: 'children'
        });
        Folder.belongsTo(models.Folder, {
            foreignKey: 'parent_id',
            as: 'parent'
        });
    }
};
Folder.init({
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    parent_id: { 
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: Folder,
            key: 'id',
            onDelete: 'cascade'
        }
    },
    user_id: { 
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
}, 
{
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'folders',
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Folder',
});
    return Folder;
};
```

And here is my connection to database:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database_name', 'user', 'pass', {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql",
    timezone: '+01:00' //Europe - Belgrade
});

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database connected successfully!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
});

const models = {
  Folder: require('../models/Folder')(sequelize, Sequelize)
};
Object.values(models)
  .forEach(model => model.associate(models));

module.exports = sequelize;
global.sequelize = sequelize;
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone more is interested, I solved the problem changing connection file to this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('bookmarkwizard', 'root', 'root', {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql",
    timezone: '+01:00' //Europe - Belgrade
});

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database connected successfully!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
});

const models = require('../models/index');

module.exports = {
    models,
    sequelize
};
global.sequelize = sequelize;
global.models = models;
```

Essence is that you should require index.js (from Models folder) because that file handle associations. I also exported that as global, and calling models as models.ModelName - and wow, associations works in a proper manner.